# Rollup in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this sample dataframe:

```
Agent     Product_type     Hours_worked     Total_spent
-----     ------------     ------------     -----------
Avi       stA              20               400
Avi       stB              30               500
Benny     stB              10               500
Benny     stB              20               300
Gilroy    stA              10               200
Gilroy    stB              20               300
Gilroy    stB              30               100
```

I wish to run a series of calculations on this dataframe, by two levels - once, as a groupby on Agent+Product_type, and the other - Just on Agent (with a generic product type, let's call it "All". For that, I wish to manipulate the above dataframe so that the resulting df I work with would look more like:

```
Agent     Product_type     Hours_worked     Total_spent
-----     ------------     ------------     -----------
Avi       stA              20               400
Avi       stB              30               500
Benny     stB              30               800
Gilroy    stA              10               200
Gilroy    stB              50               400
Avi       All              50               900
Benny     All              30               800
Gilroy    All              60               900
```

What would be the best way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: * Please explain the logic to produce the expected output. "A series of calculations on this dataframe, by two levels" is vague.

* Please show what you have tried to solve the problem. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregate function.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Agent', 'Product_type']).agg(sum).reset_index()
df3 = df2.groupby('Agent').agg(sum).reset_index()
df3['Product_type'] = 'All'

df2.append(df3).reset_index(drop=True)

    Agent Product_type  Hours_worked  Total_spent
0     Avi          stA            20          400
1     Avi          stB            30          500
2   Benny          stB            30          800
3  Gilroy          stA            10          200
4  Gilroy          stB            50          400
5     Avi          All            50          900
6   Benny          All            30          800
7  Gilroy          All            60          600
```